# Looping apply function over list of dataframes

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, save, subset

I have looked through various Overflow pages with similar questions (some linked) but haven't found anything that seems to help with this complicated task.

I have a series of data frames in my workspace and I would like to loop the same function (rollmean or some version of that) over all of them, then save the results to new data frames.

I have written a couple of lines of to generate a list of all data frames and a for loop that should iterate an apply statement over each data frame; however, I'm having problems trying to accomplish everything I'm hoping to achieve (my code and some sample data are included below):

1) I would like to restrict the `rollmean` function to all columns, except the 1st (or first several), so that the column(s) 'info' does not get averaged. *I would also like to add this column(s) back to the output data frame.*

2) I want to save the output as a new data frame (with a unique name). *I do not care if it is saved to the workspace or exported as an xlsx, as I already have batch import codes written.*

3) Ideally, I would like the resultant data frame to be the same number of observations as the input, where as `rollmean` shrinks your data. I also do not want these to become NA, so I don't want to use `fill = NA` *This could be accomplished by writing a new function, passing `type = "partial"` in `rollmean` (though that still shrinks my data by 1 in my hands), or by starting the roll mean on the nth+2 term and binding the non averaged nth and nth+1 terms to the resulting data frame. Any way is fine.* 
(see picture for detail, it illustrates what the later would look like)

My code only accomplishes parts of these things and I cannot get the for loop to work together but can get parts to work if I run them on single data frames.

**Any input is greatly appreciated because I'm out of ideas.**

```
#reproducible data frames 
a = as.data.frame(cbind(info = 1:10, matrix(rexp(200), 10)))
b = as.data.frame(cbind(info = 1:10, matrix(rexp(200), 10)))
c = as.data.frame(cbind(info = 1:10, matrix(rexp(200), 10)))
colnames(a) = c("info", 1:20)
colnames(b) = c("info", 1:20)
colnames(c) = c("info", 1:20)

#identify all dataframes for looping rollmean
dflist = as.list(ls()[sapply(mget(ls(), .GlobalEnv), is.data.frame)]

#for loop to create rolling average and save as new dataframe
for (j in 1:length(dflist)){
  list = as.list(ls()[sapply(mget(ls(), .GlobalEnv), is.data.frame)])
  new.names = as.character(unique(list))
  smoothed = as.data.frame(
     apply(
        X = names(list), MARGIN = 1, FUN = rollmean, k = 3, align = 'right'))
  assign(new.names[i], smoothed)
}
```

I also tried a nested apply approach but couldn't get it to call the rollmean/rollapply function [similar to issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17018138/using-lapply-to-apply-a-function-over-list-of-data-frames-and-saving-output-to-f) so I went back to for loops but if someone can make this work with nested applies, I'm down!

Picture is ideal output: Top is single input dataframe with colored boxes demonstrating a rolling average across all columns, to be iterated over each column; bottom is ideal output with colors reflecting the location of output for each colored window above
[image: Top is single input dataframe with colored boxes demonstrating a rolling average across all columns, to be iterated over each column; bottom is ideal output with colors reflecting the location of output for each colored window above]

Comment: J Ross, do either of the answers address your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below `dfnames` is the names of the data frames in `env`, the global environment -- we have named it `env` in case you want to later change where they are located.  Note that `ls` has a `pattern=` argument and if the data frame names have a distinct pattern then `dfnames <- ls(pattern=whatever)` could be used instead where whatever is a suitable regular expression.

Now define `make_new` which calls `rollapplyr` with a new mean function `mean3` which returns the last value of its input if the input vector has a length less than 3 and mean otherwise.  Then loop over the names using `rollappyr` with `FUN=mean3` and `partial=TRUE`.

```
library(zoo)

env <- .GlobalEnv
dfnames <- Filter(function(x) is.data.frame(get(x, env)), ls(env))

# make_new - first version
mean3 <- function(x, k = 3) if (length(x) < k) tail(x, 1) else mean(x)
make_new <- function(df) replace(df, -1, rollapplyr(df[-1], 3, mean3, partial = TRUE))

for(nm in dfnames) env[[paste(nm, "new", sep = "_")]] <- make_new(get(nm, env))
```

### Alternative version of make_new

An alternative to the first version of make_new shown above is the following second version.  In the second version instead of defining `mean3` we use just plain `mean` but specify a *vector* of widths `w` in `rollapplyr` such that `w` equals c(1, 1, 3, 3, ..., 3).  Thus it takes the mean of just the last element for the first two input components and the mean of the 3 last elements for the rest.  Note that now that we specify the widths explicitly we no longer need to specify `partial=` .

```
# make_new -- second version
make_new <- function(df) {
  w <- replace(rep(3, nrow(df)), 1:2, 1)
  replace(df, -1, rollapplyr(df[-1], w, mean))
}
```

### Note

Normally when writing R and manpulating a set of objects one stores the objects in a list rather than leaving them loose in the global environment.  We could create such a list `L` like this and then use `lapply` to create a second list `L2` containing the new versions.  Either version of `make_new` would work here.

```
L <- mget(dfnames, env)
L2 <- lapply(L, make_new)
```

Answer (score 3):

To approach this, think about one column, then one frame (which is just a list of columns), then a list of frames.

(My data used is at the bottom of the answer.)

### One Column

If you don't like the reduction of `zoo::rollmean`, then write your own:

```
myrollmean <- function(x, k, ..., type=c("normal","rollin","keep"), na.rm=FALSE) {
  type <- match.arg(type)
  out <- zoo::rollmean(x, k, ...)
  aug <- c()
  if (type == "rollin") {
    # effectively:
    #   c(mean(x[1]), mean(x[1:2]), ..., mean(x[1:j]))
    # for the j=k-1 elements that precede the first from rollmean,
    # when it'll become something like:
    # c(mean(x[3:5]), mean(x[4:6]), ...)
    aug <- sapply(seq_len(k-1), function(i) mean(x[seq_len(i)], na.rm=na.rm))
  } else if (type == "keep") {
    aug <- x[seq_len(k-1)]
  }
  out <- c(aug, out)
  out
}

myrollmean(1:8, k=3) # "normal", default behavior
# [1] 2 3 4 5 6 7
myrollmean(1:8, k=3, type="rollin")
# [1] 1.0 1.5 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0
myrollmean(1:8, k=3, type="keep")
# [1] 1 2 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

I caution that this implementation is a bit naïve at best, and needs to be fixed. Make sure that you understand what it is doing when you pick other than `"normal"` (which will not work for you, I'm just defaulting to the normal `zoo::rollmean` behavior). This function could easily be applied to other `zoo::roll*` functions.

On one column of the data:

```
rbind(
  dflist[[1]][,2],  # for comparison
  myrollmean(dflist[[1]][,2], k=3, type="keep")
)
#          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]       [,5]      [,6]      [,7]     [,8]     [,9]     [,10]
# [1,] 1.865352 0.4047481 0.1466527 1.7307097 0.08952618 0.6668976 1.0743669 1.511629 1.314276 0.1565303
# [2,] 1.865352 0.4047481 0.8055844 0.7607035 0.65562952 0.8290445 0.6102636 1.084298 1.300091 0.9941452
```

### One "frame"

Simple use of `lapply`, omitting the first column:

```
str(dflist[[1]][1:4, 1:3])
# 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ info: num  1 2 3 4
#  $ 1   : num  1.865 0.405 0.147 1.731
#  $ 2   : num  0.745 1.243 0.674 1.59
dflist[[1]][-1] <- lapply(dflist[[1]][-1], myrollmean, k=3, type="keep")
str(dflist[[1]][1:4, 1:3])
# 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ info: num  1 2 3 4
#  $ 1   : num  1.865 0.405 0.806 0.761
#  $ 2   : num  0.745 1.243 0.887 1.169
```

(For validation, column `$ 1` matches the second row in the "one column" example above.)

### List of "frames"

(I reset the data to what it was before I modified it above ... see the "data" code at the bottom of the answer.)

We nest the previous technique into another `lapply`:

```
dflist2 <- lapply(dflist, function(ldf) {
  ldf[-1] <- lapply(ldf[-1], myrollmean, k=3, type="keep")
  ldf
})
str(lapply(dflist2, function(a) a[1:4, 1:3]))
# List of 3
#  $ :'data.frame': 4 obs. of  3 variables:
#   ..$ info: num [1:4] 1 2 3 4
#   ..$ 1   : num [1:4] 1.865 0.405 0.806 0.761
#   ..$ 2   : num [1:4] 0.745 1.243 0.887 1.169
#  $ :'data.frame': 4 obs. of  3 variables:
#   ..$ info: num [1:4] 1 2 3 4
#   ..$ 1   : num [1:4] 0.271 3.611 2.36 3.095
#   ..$ 2   : num [1:4] 0.127 0.722 0.346 0.73
#  $ :'data.frame': 4 obs. of  3 variables:
#   ..$ info: num [1:4] 1 2 3 4
#   ..$ 1   : num [1:4] 1.278 0.346 1.202 0.822
#   ..$ 2   : num [1:4] 0.341 1.296 1.244 1.528
```

(Again, for simple validation, see that the first frame's `$ 1` row shows the same rolled means as the second row of the "one column" example, above.)

PS:

- if you need to skip more than just the first column, then inside the outer `lapply`, use instead `ldf[-(1:n)] <- lapply(ldf[-(1:n)], myrollmean, k=3, type="keep")` to skip the first `n` columns
- to use a window function other than `zoo::rollmean`, you'll want to change the special-cases of `myrollmean`, though it should be straight-forward enough given this example
- I use a concocted `str(...)` to shorten the output for display here. You should verify all of your data that it is doing what you expect for the whole of each frame.

---

### Reproducible Data

```
set.seed(2)
a = as.data.frame(cbind(info = 1:10, matrix(rexp(200), 10)))
b = as.data.frame(cbind(info = 1:10, matrix(rexp(200), 10)))
c = as.data.frame(cbind(info = 1:10, matrix(rexp(200), 10)))
colnames(a) = c("info", 1:20)
colnames(b) = c("info", 1:20)
colnames(c) = c("info", 1:20)
dflist <- list(a,b,c)

str(lapply(dflist, function(a) a[1:3, 1:4]))
# List of 3
#  $ :'data.frame': 3 obs. of  4 variables:
#   ..$ info: num [1:3] 1 2 3
#   ..$ 1   : num [1:3] 1.865 0.405 0.147
#   ..$ 2   : num [1:3] 0.745 1.243 0.674
#   ..$ 3   : num [1:3] 0.356 0.689 0.833
#  $ :'data.frame': 3 obs. of  4 variables:
#   ..$ info: num [1:3] 1 2 3
#   ..$ 1   : num [1:3] 0.271 3.611 3.198
#   ..$ 2   : num [1:3] 0.127 0.722 0.188
#   ..$ 3   : num [1:3] 1.99 2.74 4.78
#  $ :'data.frame': 3 obs. of  4 variables:
#   ..$ info: num [1:3] 1 2 3
#   ..$ 1   : num [1:3] 1.278 0.346 1.981
#   ..$ 2   : num [1:3] 0.341 1.296 2.094
#   ..$ 3   : num [1:3] 1.1159 3.05877 0.00506
```