# How to apply a function to a certain column for all the data frames in environment in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have lots of data frames with the same columns. What I want is to apply quantile (15% and 80%) function to the 3rd ("cpm") column for all the data frames in my environment and add the result as a new column to each data frame
All the data frames in environment are the same, here is the sample of them:

```
BD.ios = structure(list(geo = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "BD", class = "factor"), os = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "ios", class = "factor"), 
    cpm = c(0.00026978417266187, 0.000276497695852535, 0.00442228161827238, 
    0.00396317260301814, 0.0191772698764066, 0.700811773637797, 
    0.00482934642627173, 0.00201429499675114, 0.00021494623655914, 
    0.0000520855057351408)), row.names = c(12925L, 13011L, 15189L, 
18469L, 19494L, 22385L, 22594L, 29467L, 31907L, 38037L), class = "data.frame")

AE.mac = structure(list(geo = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "AE", class = "factor"), os = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "mac", class = "factor"), 
    cpm = c(0.000353264424964019, 0.00390138781055901, 0.000893105609526794, 
    0.0099634872417983, 0.00119375573921028, 0.00535134321942833, 
    0.00318471337579618, 0.000983284169124877, 0.116180371352785
    )), row.names = c(2622L, 6483L, 6898L, 9383L, 25280L, 25923L, 
29649L, 37977L, 40411L), class = "data.frame")

AF.android = structure(list(geo = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "AF", class = "factor"), os = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "android", class = "factor"), 
    cpm = c(0.193592767295597, 0.153727276424417, 0.30376596601237, 
    0.43615845874945, 0.552450120363948, 0.214786723495654, 0.206123674204523, 
    0.0250727462779332, 0.157723828668625)), row.names = c(955L, 
7975L, 8899L, 9297L, 11223L, 14963L, 17452L, 19883L, 20555L), class = "data.frame")
```

I believe, that the solution is easy and requires the use of `eapply` function, but I just can't figure it out

```
env = .GlobalEnv
eapply(env, quantile, probs = c(.15,.8))
```

This command results in an error:

```
    Error in `[.data.frame`(x, order(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing)) :
   undefined columns selected
```

**EDIT**
To make it clear, here is what I did and what I need as a result:

I had Data like this

```
data = structure(list(geo = structure(c(15L, 1L, 3L, 16L, 1L, 9L, 17L, 
23L, 29L, 52L, 26L, 55L, 34L, 46L, 25L, 52L, 17L, 15L, 27L, 35L, 
45L, 8L, 21L, 24L, 6L, 16L, 52L, 31L, 14L, 38L, 21L, 5L, 41L, 
16L, 34L, 52L, 27L, 16L, 7L, 13L, 10L, 35L, 52L, 44L, 27L, 19L, 
35L, 6L, 42L, 25L, 40L, 31L, 43L, 33L, 13L, 2L, 4L, 12L, 30L, 
44L, 51L, 38L, 35L, 28L, 52L, 32L, 20L, 19L, 34L, 56L, 51L, 53L, 
54L, 22L, 49L, 18L, 4L, 36L, 34L, 4L, 47L, 11L, 25L, 9L, 6L, 
46L, 39L, 25L, 12L, 50L, 27L, 39L, 48L, 27L, 23L, 9L, 19L, 9L, 
44L, 37L), .Label = c("AE", "AR", "AT", "AU", "AZ", "BD", "BG", 
"BO", "CA", "CD", "CH", "CO", "DK", "DZ", "EC", "EG", "ES", "FI", 
"FR", "GA", "GB", "GE", "HK", "HU", "ID", "IE", "IN", "IR", "IT", 
"KE", "KR", "LB", "LY", "MX", "MY", "NL", "PE", "PH", "PK", "PL", 
"PT", "QA", "RO", "RU", "RW", "SE", "SG", "SK", "SY", "TH", "TR", 
"US", "UY", "VN", "YE", "ZA"), class = "factor"), os = structure(c(3L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 
6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 
4L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("android", "blackberry", "ios", "mac", 
"other", "windows", "windows_phone"), class = "factor"), cpm = c(0.259529602595296, 
0.008325, 0.664507018855387, 0.000646161798914448, 0.117647058823529, 
0.630132741077424, 0.00398838150289017, 0.0986788005043583, 0.483832900637243, 
0.631904877252478, 0.00499783423573511, 0.408063887806778, 0.0916731378464372, 
1.3325069724202, 0.0112485708069297, 0.00171537666632221, 0.0129665435458787, 
0.00296443300606869, 0.22941417451864, 0.000426580184572523, 
0.206888580674988, 0.000622490272373541, 0.016084968041569, 0.119169168392267, 
0.0216352172946694, 0.0552526416330796, 0.0150883006745904, 0.324403186817902, 
0.188053932659688, 0.00389006342494715, 0.0625410833224263, 0.00111134385665529, 
0.000198831231813773, 0.00551511140525039, 1.02902374670185, 
0.574300071787509, 0.371022474579782, 0.111970606352996, 0.0000313953488372093, 
0.380035469977198, 0.0159468438538206, 0.0274524158125915, 0.237448482577744, 
0.083452302337827, 0.371352785145889, 0.129754756459319, 0.0261164794985636, 
0.602409638554217, 0.0157611216101295, 0.347620654741816, 0.130193264668441, 
0.34434946165254, 0.0693131695022054, 0.673575129533679, 0.0272002127093858, 
0.0295980803571429, 0.482425913163336, 0.00235336471280429, 0.00508469886782341, 
0.0000840689365279529, 0.236539258503618, 0.0799443865137296, 
0.296296296296296, 0.0236127508854782, 0.0152198636822762, 0.00339285714285714, 
0.150753768844221, 0.0859481582537517, 0.000587920688617856, 
0.00127715231788079, 0.150836862270619, 0.0849810111668886, 0.279757646414598, 
0.00113308871141809, 0.996427153632394, 0.00269808881394042, 
0.374087591240876, 0.228267072474796, 0.0516169572925784, 0.00902986826347305, 
0.000207365145228216, 0.244244977712646, 0.169128424850603, 0.573023255813954, 
0.0152944175375988, 1.11731843575419, 0.426646706586826, 0.0544090571844687, 
0.271433919880195, 0.0271570068233128, 0.00445611403693561, 0.00160892057026477, 
0.671800318640467, 0.0216794334441393, 0.00285318261516391, 0.295866741619575, 
0.0843108504398827, 1.60302577359969, 0.0132230143658259, 0.00246752277351996
)), row.names = c(6L, 22L, 25L, 28L, 31L, 41L, 43L, 45L, 47L, 
59L, 68L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 80L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 101L, 115L, 
117L, 121L, 123L, 125L, 140L, 144L, 149L, 151L, 165L, 169L, 170L, 
179L, 182L, 186L, 189L, 190L, 206L, 207L, 208L, 221L, 238L, 239L, 
259L, 271L, 275L, 276L, 280L, 281L, 294L, 303L, 308L, 311L, 315L, 
318L, 345L, 354L, 355L, 362L, 374L, 377L, 383L, 384L, 385L, 386L, 
394L, 405L, 407L, 408L, 419L, 422L, 424L, 425L, 427L, 442L, 445L, 
454L, 455L, 465L, 466L, 482L, 484L, 485L, 487L, 496L, 506L, 510L, 
513L, 517L, 518L, 523L, 528L, 544L, 548L, 552L, 557L, 570L, 579L, 
586L, 596L), class = "data.frame")
```

Used `split` function to get list of data frames, which separated geo+os combinations from each other and wrote them down in a list of data frames:

```
X <- split(data, list(data$geo,data$os))
```

Than I pulled data frames out from that list into the environment and deleted data frames with zero rows

```
list2env(X, envir = .GlobalEnv)
## create a function that returns a logical value
isEmpty <- function(x) {
  is.data.frame(x) && nrow(x) == 0L
}
## apply it over the environment
empty <- unlist(eapply(.GlobalEnv, isEmpty))
## remove the empties
rm(list = names(empty)[empty])
```

The desired result is a Data frame, which has 4 columns:

```
geo, os, quantile_15,quantile_80
```

Where geo+os are unique and have a certain quantile_15,quantile_80

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using lapply to apply a function over list of data frames and saving output to files with different names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17018138/using-lapply-to-apply-a-function-over-list-of-data-frames-and-saving-output-to-f)

Comment: why dont you run your code one by one? You have only 3 dataframes

Comment: What's wrong with your code? Why does it not give you what you want? If it threw an error, what was the error? Apply `quantile` to all objects (not just data.frames) in your global environment will likely result in an error since not all objects are numeric vectors.

Comment: The `probs` should be `probs = c(.15,.8)`.

Comment: I am tempted to say that it may not be a good idea to loop through all the objects in the environment. What if one of the objects in the environment is not a dataframe? I would suggest explicitly creating a list of all the dataframes that require modifications. Would something like this help? `list(BD.ios, AE.mac, AF.android) %>% map(~mutate(.x, quantile=quantile(cpm, probs = seq(.15,.8))))` (You need `dplyr` and `purrr`)

Comment: @Salman I have over a thousand data frames like this =)

@tmfmnk `probs` isn't the main issue

@VladC. yes, this would help, but I have to many data frames to type them all. And I know that all the data frames in environment are exactly the same, I made them myself

Comment: @NikitaPronin Do they perhaps all share some common prefix or suffix in the names? This would make it much easier to retrieve what you want from the environment.

Comment: @avid_useR they all have the same form - name of the dataframe is geo.os,   colnames are = geo, os, cpm. The only value that differs within each data frame is cpm. And I need to find quantile 15 and 80% for that column, which is piece a cake if there weren't so many data frames and function have to apply to a certain column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd strongly suggest [putting your data frames in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/903061) instead of just leaving them in the global environment. The answer I link to should help you understand why lists are better, and also show how you could do lists from the start instead of this "find all data frames and put them in a list" approach.

`eapply` is difficult because there's nothing built-in to let you apply, say, only to data frames. And `eapply` returns results as a `list`, so it doesn't make much sense for adding columns to existing data frames.

```
df_names = ls()[sapply(mget(ls()), is.data.frame)]
df_list = mget(df_names)
result_list = lapply(df_list, function(d) d$new_col = <code for new column>)
```

I'm not sure what you want since you don't post your desired output. `quantile(x, c(.15, .8))` returns 2 values, and your data frames have more than 2 rows, so I'm not sure what you want added - 2 new columns? 1 new column with recycling? something else?

Alternatively, maybe you just want a 2-number summary for each data frame? In that case `sapply` does nice simplification and keeps the names:

```
sapply(df_list, function(d) quantile(d$cpm, c(0.15, 0.8)))
#           AE.mac AF.android       BD.ios
# 15% 0.0009111413  0.1545266 0.0002341395
# 80% 0.0071962008  0.3567230 0.0076989311
```

---

**EDIT** based on your edits, let's work directly with `data`. We don't need to `split`, we *certainly* don't need `list2env` after the `split`. Adding columns by group is easy and efficient with `dplyr` or `data.table`. For example:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  group_by(geo, os) %>%
  summarize(quantile_15 = quantile(cpm, .15),
            quantile_80 = quantile(cpm, 0.8))
# # A tibble: 81 x 4
# # Groups:   geo [?]
#    geo   os         quantile_15 quantile_80
#    <fct> <fct>            <dbl>       <dbl>
#  1 AE    android      0.118       0.118    
#  2 AE    blackberry   0.00833     0.00833  
#  3 AR    mac          0.0296      0.0296   
#  4 AT    android      0.665       0.665    
#  5 AU    android      0.482       0.482    
#  6 AU    ios          0.374       0.374    
#  7 AU    mac          0.00903     0.00903  
# ...
```

Or with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)
data[, as.list(quantile(cpm, c(0.15, 0.8))), by = .(geo, os)]
 #    geo            os          15%          80%
 # 1:  EC           ios 2.595296e-01 2.595296e-01
 # 2:  AE    blackberry 8.325000e-03 8.325000e-03
 # 3:  AT       android 6.645070e-01 6.645070e-01
 # 4:  EG       android 1.702811e-02 8.928342e-02
 # 5:  AE       android 1.176471e-01 1.176471e-01
 # 6:  CA       windows 6.301327e-01 6.301327e-01
```

Comment: Now that's just as perfect as it can be. My approach was wrong on so many levels.